# Oracle 11g: increasing buffer cache with AMM

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, memory

On a 2-node RAC we have enabled Automatic Memory Management. The advisor views indicate that increasing the buffer cache by 4 GB will half the physical reads, and we have 4 GB to give.

How must we do this? By increasing `memory_target` and letting Oracle grab more memory for the buffer cache? Or by explicitly setting a value for `db_cache_size` (which now is zero)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the value for `db_cache_size`, and the value you set for it will be considered the minimum value it can be with AMM enabled.

Comment: Thank you, so I guess that in order to not affect anything else, I should also increase the memory_target and memory_max_target, correct?

Comment: @GID If the current value of them does not allow the `db_cache_size` to be 4G (because let's say, `memory_target=3G`), then yes, of course.